# How to serialize a list of objects into list of items for primary key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

With django-rest-framework, how can I serialize the many elements of a one-to-many relationship into a list of simple values from one field of those items? For example in

```py
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to get

```json
{
    'album_name': 'Things We Lost In The Fire',
    'artist': 'Low',
    'tracks': [15, 12, 17, 23]
}
```

Comment: Use django serializers 

`from django.core import serializers`
`data = serializers.serialize("xml", SomeModel.objects.all())`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **`PrimaryKeyRelatedField(...)`** as

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Album
```

Comment: your answer is correct but PrimaryKeyRelatedField attribute is in "serializers" which is imported like this "from rest_framework import serializers" not "serializer"